Почему Visual Studio Code подчеркивает мой `return` красным?
Написал код на Pyhton :
a = 100  # сумма вклада
years = 2 # количество лет
b = 10   # проценты годовых
def bank(a, years):
    for year in range(years):
        a = a * (b / 100) + a
    return "%.2f" % a
print (bank(a, years))
bank(a, years)

Код работает исправно.. Но почему то Visual Studio Code подчеркивает return красным(как ошибку). Вопрос: Почему?

А если навести на это подчёркивание, то что пишет? Возможно, это какой-то линтер ругается, например, что вы используете древний способ форматирования данных.

Если навести на подчеркивание пишет: Непоследовательное использование вкладок и пробелов в отступах Pylance.        Уже все пробелы попробовал не получается.

В приведенном коде все хорошо 4-8-4 пробела — Pylance не ругается.

Перед строкой a = a * (b / 100) + a явно символ табуляции стоит

@DaniilLoban нужно скопировать код из исходника вопроса, тогда будет видно, что в строке после for первый отступ табом сделан: https://i.sstatic.net/7AsFx.png

@insolor я так и сделал, с самого начала, вручную не стал набирать)
